# Spring MVC with Google Charts, what is the best way to create javascript data tables?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc, google-visualization

I'm building a Spring MVC application where I create graphs in browser using data from database. I have already created data handling in the backend and I have needed keys and values in a Java map. I was wondering what is the best way to put data to javascript data tables which Google Charts are using. I found that there is [Google Visualization Data Source Library](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/dev/dsl_intro) but I didn't found much info or examples of that.

I'm leaning on sending the java map via model to javascript and parse the data there. But if that javascript parsing could somehow be avoided it would be great...

Answer (score 2):

The data source library you linked to is a complete package for handling database access and returning data to your charts via the Visualization API's Query interface.  If you don't want to use that, you have a spectrum of options which vary the workload from the server to the client.  On one end, you can offload the parsing to the client by passing your data object as-is (or a JSON representation of it) and let the client parse that into a DataTable.  On the other end, you can create a Java class that replicates the structure of a DataTable constructor's object-literal parameter (see [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)).  Everything in between is transforming your data on the server into a format that is easier for the client to parse into a DataTable.

As far as I am aware, there is no pre-packaged DataTable class for Java, other than what comes in the data source library you linked to.